# node.js "Command failed: execvp(): Permission denied" error on MasOS X

Tags: macos, node.js

I'm trying to run a program (e.g. "/Applications/Safari.app") from node using `child_process.execFile` but it fails with the error:

```
"Command failed: execvp(): Permission denied"
```

It works well on Ubuntu and Windows, but on MacOS this issue appears. Am I missing something?

Comment: What happens if you start node with sudo?

Answer (score 2):

`/Applications/Safari.app` is actually a directory ([application bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AboutBundles/AboutBundles.html)), not an executable file.

I think the simplest solution would be to use `/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari` instead.

Comment: This was what I needed. Great answer for ~5 years ago. Thanks!

Comment: I've been looking all around for this solution too. Thanks!